# How to excldue null values using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle, null, expression, substr

The following statement retrieve the value of sub tag *msg_id* from MISC column if the sub stag contain value like %PACS%.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(MISC, '(^|\s|;)msg_id = (.*?)\s*(;|$)',1,1,NULL,2) AS TRANS_REF FROM MISC_HEADER
WHERE MISC LIKE '%PACS%';
```

I notice the query return record with null value (without msg_id) as well. Any idea if can exclude those null records from the syntax of REGEXP_SUBSTR, without adding any where clause.

Sample data of MISC:

1. channel=atm ; phone=0123 ; msg_id=PACS00812 ; ustrd=U123
2. channel=pos; phone=9922; ustrd=U156

The second record without msg_id, so it need to be excluded.

Comment: No, I don't know of a way to do that without adding logic to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for `MISC`?

Comment: @Nick,sample data
 1. channel=atm ; phone=0123 ; msg_id=PACS00812 ; ustrd=U123
 2.channel=pos; phone=9922; ustrd=U156

The second record without msg_id, so it need to be excluded.

Comment: @user2102665 please add the data to your question - it's too hard to understand it written in a comment.

Comment: @Nick, added..thanks

Comment: @user2102665 for the sample data you have shown, the value without `msg_id` would be excluded by your existing `WHERE` clause since it doesn't contain the string `PACS`

Comment: @Nick, no, i'm unlikely to use WHERE clause since the application need to be able to display all records when do not supply any value to MISC

Answer (score 0):

This method does not use REGEXP so may not be suitable for you.
However, it does satisfy your requirement.
This takes your embedded list of msg_id, breaks it out to a row for each component for an ID (I've assumed you do have something uniquely identifies each record).
It then only returns the original row where one of the rows for the ID has 'PACS' in it.

```
WITH thedata
     AS (SELECT 1 AS theid
              , 'channel=atm ; phone=0123 ; msg_id=PACS00812 ; ustrd=U123'
                   AS msg_id
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'channel=pos; phone=9922; ustrd=U156' FROM DUAL)
   , mylist
     AS (SELECT theid, COLUMN_VALUE AS msg_component
         FROM   thedata
              , XMLTABLE(('"' || REPLACE(msg_id, ';', '","') || '"')))
SELECT *
FROM   thedata td
WHERE  EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
           FROM   mylist m
           WHERE  m.theid = td.theid
           AND    m.msg_component LIKE '%PACS%')
```

Thedata sub-query is simply to generate a couple of records and pretend to be your table. You could remove that and substitute your actual table name.
There are other ways to break up an embedded list including ones that use REGEXP, I just find the XMLTABLE method 'cleaner'.